When IAP is disabled (e.g. error) the underlying service becomes publicly available
IAP may disable itself, e.g. if the related backend service temporarily errors.
This leads to the backend service to be publicly available on the internet.
The expected behavior is for the service to be inaccessible unless via IAP.
Am I missing some configuration?

Hmm, can you provide more information? How is your IAP configured? And are you sure you set your Firewall Rules to block public access?

Can you detail the backend service type? How it is created? Why it fails?
